# auto fit div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have nested divs the parent div is named "rDiv" lets just say that the structure 
is like -->

```
______________________________
|                             |
|                             |
|     [1]-child div1          |
|                             |<-[rDiv]-parent div  
|              [2]-child div2 |
|                             |
|_____________________________|
```

`rDiv` is the parent div and the children of that div are `[1]` and `[2]`.

What I'm trying to do is to make is so that when you click the children div(s) it auto-fits to the parent div height and width.

I tried it in JQuery using :

```
.css({width:,height});
```

But it over lapses the parent div.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: What do you mean, *lapses*? Can you provide a screenshot, or better, a jsfiddle like Avaq suggested?

Comment: He tries to say that the child div overlaps not over lapses :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need. So I've created two examples.
The first one uses CSS position `properties` to resize height and width to 100% relatively to parent div.
The second one makes use of jQuery some power of `inner/outer width/height`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Dtjw/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#div2').click(function() {
$("#div2").css('width',$("#div1").css('width'));
$("#div2").css('height',$("#div1").css('height'));
})
```

Or shorter

```
$('#div2').click(function() {
$("#div2").css({width:$("#div1").css('width'), height:$("#div1").css('height')});
})
```